# How to show translated taxonomy terms in term listing in content listing style

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have question about translation of taxonomy terms in Drupal 8. Let's assume this configuration:

New created vocabulary, vocabulary language - not specified, terms language - not specified, show language selector, enable translation.

With this config, I should be able to translate new created taxonomy terms, if I select specific language while creating one. So I create taxonomy term in English language. Then I go and translate that term by clicking the "translate" tab in this term. I fill all values and save the form. Term is now translated to another language.

And now comes the difference - when I do the same approach with content, in content overview I see all nodes - original, and also translated. When I do this with taxonomy terms, in vocabulary listing I see only taxonomy term which was created first (so in my example the English one) - see the image.

[image]

How can I achieve the same behaviour as in content listing? I am expecting, that all terms will be listed here (as in content overview), or at least, when in specified language, terms with this language set should be shown (e.g. in English only links in english translations, if they exists). Taxonomy terms and nodes are all entities, so I would expect the same behaviour while translating them... Or is this a bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it kind of is a bug.

The page is I think one of the the only two lists (the other is comments) that is hardcoded and *not* a view.

Views have configurable behavior to show show the entity in the best translation, or show the default translation.

You can replace this list with a view yourself, just create a view that lists terms on that path. Views doesn't support a few features of that UI however, specifically, that is the drag and drop hierarchy and weight handling. if you don't need that, fine. If you do, you might need to look for contrib modules that offer such features, I'm not sure if there are some for Drupal 8.

Comment: Well, thank you for response. I am just surprised, that when lot of things changes in Drupal 8, some of the old "bad practices" still remains... Or nobody really care for full functional transliteration?

Comment: is there some patch for this bug (is this bug addressed on Drupal.org issue queue), if I do not want to use custom view? Or we have to solve it ourselves?

Comment: do you have some update about this issue? I quickly checked Drupal 9 and it seems like nobody fixed this problem (existing more that 5 years). Do you have knowledge about issue on drupal.org, where this is discussed or any module, which will replace this buggy page? It seems like this is the only one page in Drupal 9 without view.... That is very sad.